# Why does passing null to varargs give length 1?

Tags: java, variadic-functions

I've been using Java's variable arguments in my methods, and have been testing them by passing in null as a parameter:

```
public void method(Object A, Object...b) {
    if(A == null || b == null || b.length == 0) return;
...(something that invokes b)...

public void test() {
    method(new Object(), null)
...
```

At the beginning of the method, I checked for null as the parameter, and even for the length to be 0. But since the test kept failing because of a `NullPointerException`, I ran the debugger, and `b` was length 1! It even said when I clicked on the disclosure triangle for `b`,

```
all elements are null
```

I eventually resolved this by checking for length 1 and element 0 is null, but
does anyone have an explanation for why Java does this? Thanks!

Comment: Think of varargs as an array of arguments. When you pass null you're actually passing `[null]` ;)

Comment: yes, `b` is an array of length 1 that contains `null`. If you want 0, do not pass anything for `b`

Comment: and if for any reason you _do_ want `b == null` then cast: `x.method(new Object(), (Object[])null)`

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Because you're passing in a value of `null`.

If you want your varargs method to receive an empty array, either

1. pass that explicitly:

   ```
   method(new Object(), new Object[0])
   ```
2. don't pass anything at all:

   ```
   method(new Object())
   ```

Option 2 would be more idiomatic.

Comment: for me both options ae not working. SM.getObject() != null && SM.getObject().length > 0 this case for me always true even if i do not pass anything

Answer (score 4):

`null` is a value.

You provide a single value for the varargs argument, so the array will be `new Object[] { null }` which has a length of 1.

If you wanted to pass no values at all, you'd have to call `method(new Object());`.